# Pushing data from a structure into a stack in C

Tags: c, data-structures, segmentation-fault, stack, push

The task of the program is to push all the data from a structure into a stack, using `memcpy`.
Upon execution, it successfully enters the data into the structure, but reaches a segmentation fault when it comes to the `push()` function.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <mem.h>

typedef struct STD {
   char ime [50];
   int fn;
   float usp;
   } STD;


 typedef struct STACK {
    STD *s;
    STACK *next;

    } STACK;
  int push (void *a, int siz,  STACK **sst) {
STACK *snew;
snew = (STACK *) malloc (siz + 1);
memcpy (snew->s, a, siz); 
 snew -> next = *sst;
 *sst = snew;


 }

int main () {
STACK *st;
STD  ss;

printf ("Vyvedi ime");
gets (ss.ime);
ss.ime[49] = 0;
printf ("Vyvedi fn");
scanf ("%d", &ss.fn);

printf ("Vyvedi usp");
scanf ("%f", &ss.usp);



push (&ss, sizeof(ss) , &st);



system ("pause");      }
```

Don't know if it matters,  I use DevC as a compiler.

Comment: And I'm expecting that you'll ask question any minute now...

Comment: @abelenky - it's pretty clear that segmentation fault is the issue

Comment: @Steve Townsend: most regular users of SO have gotten very clear that they are sick of, "Here's my code-dump, pleaze fix it" type questions.  We all want to see from the poster: What did you expect? What are you actually getting? What have you tried and where are you stuck?   When people ask real questions, it is easier to provide real answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is wrong:

```
STACK *snew;
snew = (STACK *) malloc (siz + 1);
memcpy (snew->s, a, siz);
```

`snew->s` is not initialized when you `memcpy a` into it.  I would expect to see two `malloc`s - one for `STACK*` and another for `STD*`, which you would then use to seed `snew->s` before copying stuff into it.

```
STACK *snew;
snew = (STACK *) malloc (sizeof(STACK));
snew->s = (STD*) malloc(sizeof(STD));
memcpy (snew->s, a, siz);
```

Alternatively you could use a single `malloc`, and point `snew->s` to the appropriate offset within it (after you've left space for the `STACK struct`).

```
STACK *snew;
snew = (STACK *) malloc (sizeof(STACK) + siz + 1);
snew->s = (char*)snew + sizeof(STACK);
memcpy (snew->s, a, siz);
```

The `siz` parameter on your `push` function seems superfluous, since you are always passing in a `struct STD`.

Answer (score 1):

1. note you do not allocate a space for `s`
2. you need to initialize the `st` to `NULL`
3. pls check that `snew` is not `NULL`

i.e.

```
int push (void *a, int siz,  STACK **sst) {
  STACK *snew (STACK *) malloc (siz + 1);
  snew->s = (STD *) mallos (sizeof(STD)); // <-----------
  memcpy (snew->s, a, siz); 
  snew -> next = *sst;
  *sst = snew;
 }
```

And it looks like there are other issues there, start using meaningful names, not `ss`, `st`..

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you do, Dalamar:
1. If you have a debugger, and you know how to use it, then step through the push() function to see where the segmentation fault occurs.
2. Otherwise, put a printf statement between every line in push():

```
printf ("1\n") ;  
...  
printf ("2\n") ;  
...
```

This will also tell you where the segmentation fault occurs.
If you're still stuck, then get back to us with the new info.

Comment: That isn't reliable.  `fprintf(stderr, "1\n");` works better.  `printf` writes to `stdout`, which can be buffered, and not necessarily line-buffered, and so in event of a crash you can lose `printf` statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

#include "linkedlist.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 LinkedList myList;
 Node *node  ;
 int choice = 0 , index=0 ;
 string agentName, caseDesc ;
 int caseNo;
 do
 {

     cout<< "\n Enter 1 Add a new node to the end \n";
     cout<< " Enter 2 Add a new node to the beginning \n";
     cout<< " Enter 3 Print out the entire list \n";
     cout<< " Enter 4 Remove a node from the list \n";
     cout<< " Enter 5 Quit the program \n";
     cout<< " Enter your choice : ";
     cin>> choice;
     switch(choice){
       case 1:
                   //  Insert appropriate code here ....
       break;

       case 2:
                   //  Insert appropriate code here ....
       break;

       case 3:
                   //  Insert appropriate code here ....
       break;

       case 4:
                   //  Insert appropriate code here ....        
       break;

       case 5:
         exit(1);
       break;      

       default :
         cout<<"\n   Invalid Option, Please try again .....\n";
       break;

     }

 }while (true);




 system("PAUSE");   
 return 0;
```

Comment: Please take your time to reformat the code. Take a look at the formatting help